# Heap pollution consequences

Tags: java, heap-memory, heap-corruption

"Everybody" knows [heap pollution](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/156008) can cause unexpected `ClassCastException`s.

What are other consequences of heap pollution (w.r.t. other types of exceptions, security, performance...)?

Comment: Given the way it's defined in the JLS, I'd be surprised if there were any other consequences...